# Tener un select seleccionado con jquery

Tags: jquery

Tengo esta función que dependiendo del valor que ponga que en mi select "duracionTurno" muestra unas cosas u otras. Todo me funciona a la perfección, el único problema es que en uno de los if he puesto que si tiene el valor '16:00' horas seleccionado, seleccione el valor '10:00' en el select 'selectTurno' y esconda el valor "16:00". El valor "16:00" me lo esconde todas las veces que cambio el valor de el select "duraciónTurno", pero el seleccionar el valor "10:00" solo me funciona una única vez. Yo quiero que lo haga siempre.

> Archivo JavaScript

```
$("#duracionTurno").change(function(){
    var elegirActividades = $("#selectActividad").val();
    var elegirDuraciones = $("#selectDuracion").val();
    var selectTurno = $('#selectTurno').val();

    if(elegirActividades == 18 && elegirDuraciones == 'Avanzado - 48 horas' || elegirActividades == 18 && elegirDuraciones == 'Extremo - 10 días'){
        $('#otrasActividades').show();
        $('.sw-btn-next').addClass("disabled").attr("disabled", true);
    }else if(elegirActividades == 18 && elegirDuraciones == 'Intermedio - 8 horas'){
        $("#selectTurno option[value='16:00']").hide();
        $("#selectTurno option[value='10:00']").attr("selected",true);
        $('#otrasActividades').hide();
        $('.sw-btn-next').removeClass("disabled").attr("disabled", false);
    }else if(elegirActividades == 18 && elegirDuraciones == 'Iniciación - 4 horas'){
        $("#selectTurno option[value='16:00']").show();
        $('#otrasActividades').hide();
        $('.sw-btn-next').removeClass("disabled").attr("disabled", false);
    }else{
        $('#otrasActividades').hide();
        $('.sw-btn-next').removeClass("disabled").attr("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

> Archivo HTML

```
<div class="form-group" id="elegirActividad">
    <select id="selectActividad" class="form-control marginRight">
            <option value="vacio" disabled selected>Selecciona una actividad</option>
            <option value="2">Paintball</option>
            <option value="18">Supervivencia</option>
        </select>
 </div>
<div id="duracionTurno">
    <div class="form-group" id="elegirDuracion">
        <label for="mainActividad">Selecciona una duración</label>
        <select id="selectDuracion" class="form-control marginRight">
            <option value="vacio" disabled selected>Selecciona una duración</option>
            <option value="Iniciación - 4 horas">Iniciación - 4 horas</option>
            <option value="Intermedio - 8 horas">Intermedio - 8 horas</option>
            <option value="Avanzado - 48 horas">Avanzado - 48 horas</option>
            <option value="Extremo - 10 días">Iniciación - 4 horas</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="elegirTurno">
        <label for="mainActividad">Selecciona un turno</label>
        <select id="selectTurno" class="form-control marginRight">
            <option value="vacio" disabled selected>Selecciona un turno</option>
            <optgroup label="Turnos de mañana">
                <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
            <optgroup label="Turnos de tarde">
                <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: La parte HTML esta echo con una petición AJAX llamando a un archivo PHP que llama a la base de datos por los archivos y es bastante extenso, creo que ponerlo solo liaría más las cosas.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tu pregunta no es del todo clara, lo que dices aquí: *pero el seleccionar el valor "10:00" solo me funciona una única vez* no se entiende. No explicas lo que debería ocurrir cuando seleccionas la hora `10:00`.

Comment: Ya he añadido el HTML. 
Lo que quiero decir es que cuando elijo en el select "selectActividad" la opción de "Supervivencia" con valor "18" y en el select "selectDuracion" cojo la opción "Intermedio - 8 horas", en el select "selectTurno" desaparece la opción de "16:00" y se queda seleccionado el de "10:00", pero esto solo me lo hace una vez, es decir, si vuelvo a cambiar el select "selectDuracion" y luego vuelvo a poner la opción "Intermedio - 8 horas", en el select "selecTurno" desaparece la opción "16:00" pero no se queda seleccionado la opción "10:00"

Comment: A ver si podemos comprender el asunto. Por lo que dices se opera un cambio en el `selectDuracion` y tú quieres después de ese cambio que ocurra algo. ¿He entendido bien? Eso no puede ocurrir, porque en tu código jQuery tú no estás escuchando los eventos `on change` del select `selectDuracion`. El único cambio que tú controlas en el código es el de `duracionTurno`

Comment: Perdón se me había olvidado poner el div en el que se miraba si se hacía cambios ("duracionTurno"). Ya lo he añadido, espero que quede más claro ahora

Comment: No termino de entender la cuestión. Según el código jQuery, lo único que se está controlando son los cambios en el select cuyo id es `duracionTurno`, pero tú quieres que ocurra un cambio cuando cambies algo en el `selectDuracion`, pero ese select no tiene un evento `change` en el código, por lo tanto, nada ocurrirá cuando cambies algo en él.

Comment: He intentado poner que me salga el evento change como tu dices directamente en el select, pero no me funciona, sin embargo si lo dejo tal y como lo tengo puesto si ocurre todo lo anterior mencionado. Ya que el contenido del div "duracionTurno" cambia cuando selecciono otra opción en el select "selectDuracion".

Comment: No logro entenderte. ¿Podrías por favor [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/131004/edit) explicando con precisión lo que quieres lograr, llamando a cada elemento por su nombre. Intuyo que no es un problema complicado, pero al no saber explicarlo bien quizá tú mismo estás algo perdido en la lógica del programa. Se necesita una explicación del tipo: *en el select cuyo id es tal, tengo un valor y quiero que al cambiar el select cuyo id es tal, se ponga el valor tal en el select cuyo id es tal...*.

Comment: Quiero que cuando en el select con id (selectDuracion) tenga seleccionado el valor (Intermedio - 8horas), en el select con id (selectTurno) se quede seleccionado el valor de (10:00), y no se muestre el del valor (16:00). Y esta operación la hace perfectamente bien solo una vez, es decir,  si yo hago esta operación sale bien, pero luego cambio el valor del select con id (selectDuracion) a otro valor cualquiera y luego vuelvo a ponerlo en el valor de (Intermedio - 8 horas), esta segunda vez el select con id (selectTurno) no muestra el valor (16:00) pero no me deja seleccionado el valor (10:00).

Comment: ***pero luego cambio el valor del select con id (selectDuracion) a otro valor cualquiera*** ... significa que en el `selectDuracion` ocurre un evento el cual no es controlado en el código.  Tienes que crear un escuchador parecido a este: `$("#selectDuracion").change(function(){ //código a ejecutar cuando ese select cambie` en el cual actualizarás lo que haya que actualizar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te propongo esta solución.

1. Para establecer qué valor tiene que seleccionarse, con esto bastaría: `$("#selectTurno").val("10:00");`. Haciendo eso, el elemento `selected` será aquel cuyo valor sea `10:00`.
2. En vez de intentar ocultar las opciones con `hide`, lo cual no es para nada evidente y tomando en cuenta que según el navegador podrías tener algún problema con `hide`, puedes jugar con la propiedad `enabled/disabled`, de modo que, cuando esté seleccionado `10:00` desactive la opción `16:00`, y viceversa.
3. En jQuery actualmente, se recomienda usar `prop` en lugar de `attr`, por eso he cambiado en el código todos los `attr` por `prop`.

El código se podría mejorar y podrías implementar algo parecido a: *activa solamente la opción seleccionada y desactiva todas las otras*. Sería muy útil en el caso de que puedan haber varias opciones y te evitaría el dolor de cabeza de tener que estar ocultando y mostrando opciones según el caso.

Espero que esto te sirva para resolver el problema.

```js
$("#selectDuracion").change(function() {
  var elegirActividades = $("#selectActividad").val();
  var elegirDuraciones = $("#selectDuracion").val();
  var selectTurno = $('#selectTurno').val();
  if (elegirActividades == 18 && elegirDuraciones == 'Avanzado - 48 horas' || elegirActividades == 18 && elegirDuraciones == 'Extremo - 10 días') {
    $('#otrasActividades').show();
    $('.sw-btn-next').addClass("disabled").prop("disabled", true);
  } else if (elegirActividades == 18 && elegirDuraciones == 'Intermedio - 8 horas') {
    $("#selectTurno option[value='16:00']").prop('disabled', true);
    $("#selectTurno option[value='10:00']").prop('disabled', false);
    $("#selectTurno").val("10:00");
    $('#otrasActividades').hide();
    $('.sw-btn-next').removeClass("disabled").prop("disabled", false);
  } else if (elegirActividades == 18 && elegirDuraciones == 'Iniciación - 4 horas') {
    $("#selectTurno option[value='16:00']").prop('disabled', false);
    $("#selectTurno option[value='10:00']").prop('disabled', true);
    $("#selectTurno").val("16:00");
    $('#otrasActividades').hide();
    $('.sw-btn-next').removeClass("disabled").prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $('#otrasActividades').hide();
    $('.sw-btn-next').removeClass("disabled").prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Archivo HTML
<div class="form-group" id="elegirActividad">
  <select id="selectActividad" class="form-control marginRight">
            <option value="vacio" disabled selected>Selecciona una actividad</option>
            <option value="2">Paintball</option>
            <option value="18">Supervivencia</option>
        </select>
</div>
<div id="duracionTurno">
  <div class="form-group" id="elegirDuracion">
    <label for="mainActividad">Selecciona una duración</label>
    <select id="selectDuracion" class="form-control marginRight">
            <option value="vacio" disabled selected>Selecciona una duración</option>
            <option value="Iniciación - 4 horas">Iniciación - 4 horas</option>
            <option value="Intermedio - 8 horas">Intermedio - 8 horas</option>
            <option value="Avanzado - 48 horas">Avanzado - 48 horas</option>
            <option value="Extremo - 10 días">Extremo - 10 días</option>
        </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="elegirTurno">
    <label for="mainActividad">Selecciona un turno</label>
    <select id="selectTurno" class="form-control marginRight">
            <option value="vacio" disabled selected>Selecciona un turno</option>
            <optgroup label="Turnos de mañana">
                <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
            <optgroup label="Turnos de tarde">
                <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
        </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Al final se arregló simplemente cambiando los attr por el prop. Mil gracias!!!

Comment: @auremanci me alegro. Cuando puedas lee la sección: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Saludos.